What day count convention for pricing
Imagine looking at some equity implied vol surface on Bloomberg. You see a call implied volatility in the grid. Now you want to convert this vol into a price. For that, you will use Black-Scholes formula. And in this formula, the expiry is a number while a call as an expiry which is a date, and a pricing date. From these two dates and a day count convention (and a calendar) you can get the number you want to use a expiry in the Black-Scholes formula. Same if you want to price that call in a Monte-Carlo (MC) setting. (All dates appearing are converted, with the pricing date as basis/reference date, and a day-count convention, into real numbers etc.) What is this day count convention ?
Now imagine I have a fixed VS floating vanilla swap. Both swap's legs have a day count convention used to compute the year fractions needed for the zero-coupons and the EURIBOR rates (let's say the swap is an ICE EURIBOR swap). And it can happen that these two day count conventions are different. Suppose they are different. And suppose that you price that swap in a short rate model. You diffuse the spot rate across both legs dates and for that you need to have real numbers at the end, as in the simple example, hence a day count convention (for the conversion) but for the swap you have two. Do you choose one of them for the MC ? If not, which day count convention is it ? ACT/365.25 FIXED ? (Keeping then legs' day count conventions only for "accounting" (i.e. computing year fractions).)
To put it simple : how, in a MC setting, do you convert dates into real numbers ? As the MC price is a limit, I would say that any reasonable day count convention would suit, but which one do practitioners use ?

Does this answer your question? Bloomberg terminal option data calculation

Before answering, could you tell my if you understand my point with the swap and its two legs each with a different day count convention ? (I am not sure my question is clear enough.)

Do you know swap daycount conventions and what should be used for risk free rates? If so, the answer should be clear. A market standard FXFL SOFR swap is ACT/360 on both legs. You specifically asked about Bloomberg and my link replicates Bloomberg's pricing to the exact decimal.

I perfectly know that. But would I have to simulate something on dates of both legs, I would need to have a common daycount convention (DCC for short)  for that. That's my point. I think that this common DCC is not related to the market (as it is only used as common DCC in a MC setting to convert into numbers dates from both legs at the same time) and that it cannot hence be one the DCC of one of the legs. (In case they have different DCCs.) Do I make sense ? Maybe I shouldn't have taken the call option example, but only the swap one ?

What's the point of using MC for a vanilla swap?

Imagine then a basis swap instead of a swap. ANy product you'd have to diffuse the state variable you smilulate across dates of two legs having different DCCs. For such a product you'd need a common "simulation" DCC.

Every market and product has its own pricing conventions that participants are just expected to know. Would guess most vol markets are actual/365 for black-scholes day-count while most swap markets are actual/360. Bonds can be 30E/360 etc

I am not asking for the day count convention. I am asking the day count convention used for monte carlo (as there are products having several legs and one day count convention per leg you can be consistent in converting dates to real numbers in MC if you don't use a unique day count convention).

you use the day convention of each part to convert to a number, that what a day count is. It takes dates and gives you numbers. So do monte-carlo on dates, then use those dates to get the right year fractions to convert vols to variances.

Doing MC on dates ? What the hell is that supposed to mean ?

The time steps are to dates. T0=13june24 T1=20june24 T2=30june24

I thought brownian motions were defined for non-negative t's, I did not know that you could defined a brownian motion on a date. How is that defined ?

Use your day_count conversion formulas

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am sorry to say that but you are not making any sense.

I've answered in the chat
